# TypeError: '[object HTMLInputElement]' is not a function (evaluating 'elem[ type ]()') in jQuery form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

Has never run into this issue? I'm getting this error in the latest release of jQuery. I tried with version 1.6.2 and there is no issue.

```
TypeError: '[object HTMLInputElement]' is not a function (evaluating 'elem[ type ]()')

line 3175
```

Has anything changed that we should be aware of?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Looks more like you are passing a wrong argument somewhere.

Comment: Maybe try ```$(form).submit()```.

Comment: It's your selector. jQuery objects are different than DOM Object. I can see you're trying to apply a jquery function to a DOM element. Do this: `$(yourelement).submit(...` instead of `yourelement.subimit(...`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This usually happens if any of your `input` tag's name is `submit`. 
For example,

```
<form id="frm">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

On the above code, `document.getElementById("frm").submit` represents the `input` element. When you apply `()` to `submit` It shows this error.

Comment: Thanks Shiplu. That was it. I guess I have to be more careful about what name to use when using jQuery.

Comment: @juminoz: That's not related to jQuery, it is a general JavaScript/DOM/scope problem.

Comment: @FelixKling That may be true, but since I didn't see the same issue in version 1.6.2, I assumed that something might have changed.

Comment: This is mentioned in the jQuery docs, but the wording is rather vague: 'Name conflicts can cause confusing failures.' So good thing there's something like the SO community for practical answers to practical problems.

Comment: Solved something for me, too. Good rule I will now follow is don't use IDs that are the same as the input type.

Comment: This was driving me crazy all day $('#form").submit() and $("#form").trigger('submit') nothing would work, my submit button was named submit...changed it and now working, thanks!

Comment: This answer is very good (saved me a lot of time!) but does anyone know the reason why jQuery won't allow `name="submit"`? It would be good to know that.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that this error will occur when using the `onclick` attribute to call a JavaScript function with the same name as *either* the `id` *or* `name` attributes on an `input` element:

```
<input id='foo' name='fooName' onclick='foo();'> <!-- BAD: id matches function -->

<input id='fooId' name='foo' onclick='foo();'> <!-- BAD: name matches function -->

<input id='fooId' name='fooName' onclick='foo();'> <!-- WORKS! -->
```

This behavior occurs irrespective of input type.

Comment: This is exactly what was causing the error for me. I had a checkbox setup as such:  
`<input type="checkbox" id="toggleCheck" name="toggleCheck" onClick="toggleCheck();">`  

It worked properly once I renamed the "name" and "id" tags:  
`<input type="checkbox" id="toggleCheckbox" name="toggleCheckbox" onClick="toggleCheck();">`

Comment: took me ages to found your solution because nobody wrote a real example with ids and names.. otherwise these guys would realize, that matching names cause this error. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I hade a similar issue with safari recently on a bit of javascript to submit a form. Turned out to be due to the submit input element having the `name="submit"`, which was conflicting causing it to return it as not being a function.