# ASP .NET MVC cannot submit form with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I need your help. I am trying to realize a live search. So whenever I switch from one TextBox to another, a form should be submitted, to update the URL and to pass the data to the controller. It works perfectly fine when I click the submit button but it does not work the way I want.

*Here is my code:*

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string number, string caption)
{
    //Fetch data from the database
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number').change(function () {
        $('#filter').submit();
    });
});

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "filter" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
        Number:
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @Html.TextBox("Number", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "number" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
        Caption:
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @Html.TextBox("Caption", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "caption" })
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class=" btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Output HTML:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number').change(function () {
        $('#filter').submit();
    });
});
</script>

<form action="/" id="filter" method="get">    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
        Number:
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="number" name="Number" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
        Caption:
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="caption" name="Caption" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class=" btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Browser Console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem[type] is not a function
at Object.trigger (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:2991:18)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3618:17)
at Function.each (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:625:20)
at init.each (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:255:17)
at init.trigger (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3617:15)
at init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as submit] (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3671:9)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:49782/:63:26)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3077:9)
at HTMLInputElement.eventHandle (http://localhost:49782/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:2695:28)
```

Comment: Are you sure the textbox on the compiled form has the id number? Please verify this

Comment: @Satpal $(document).ready(function(){}); does not solve the problem nor the script at the bottom of the page. The _onChange_ event fires up, if I put _confirm("Test")_ inside the script, only the form is not submitted.

Comment: @Nils I can find the TextBox ID in the generated HTML

Comment: I am not sure why your form is not submitting.. the code looks fine.. As you said clicking on the button will submit.. why dont you first check if the button is clicked programatically is the form submitted.. `$('#submit').trigger('click')`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy unfortunately it does not work either...

Comment: @Slava check your console for errors if any

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I've just updated the question. Yes, there are some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is looking for the tag with ID `#number`. Because browsers mostly read the source code from the top to the bottom, the code will be evaluated well before the `#number` `<input>` is even declared. This means that jQuery will not find it and will therefore not attach the event. If you move the script after the HTML, or wrap it into `document.ready`, it will work as expected:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
  $('#number').change(function () {
     $('#filter').submit();
  });
} );

//or simpler equivalent

$( function () { ... } );
```

This however will still not work as you want, because each time the input changes, the whole page will be posted back to the server, so user will have to wait for the entire page to reload after he tries to switch focus from one input to another. This is not very convenient and you would probably be better off changing the logic to use AJAX calls and dynamically update the search results. Although it is not a requirement, it is a nice to have and user-friendly approach :-) .

### Update - solution to submit error

I have just [found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672914/typeerror-object-htmlinputelement-is-not-a-function-evaluating-elem-type) for the error you get trying to submit. Your submit button's **id is `submit`**. This is not "wrong" per se, but it causes a problem trying to submit with jQuery. You see, because the button is inside your form, when jQuery returns the `#filter` form, when you try to use `submit()` on it, JavaScript finds your `submit` **button** in scope and **thinks that you want to "call it"** - hence you get the error, because you you cannot "call" an element. This might also happen if you use `submit` as the name of a button.

The best and easiest solution for you will be to change the `id` to something else:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class=" btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately _$(document).ready()_ does not solve the problem. The event fires if I add _confirm("Test")_, only the form is not submitted. 
How can I realize that with AJAX? Thanks!

Comment: Have you wrapped your code inside the ready handler? In case yes, it should definitely fire, so this is quite surprising. Could you also post the HTML code from the browser (without Razor)?
With AJAX you would create a HTTP GET request that would send the contents of your inputs to a ASP.NET Web API controller, that would return the results as JSON objects you would then transform into HTML output for your page. There should be many tutorials for this on the net :-) .

Comment: I've just updated my question and posted HTML code. I will try to realize it with AJAX. Thanks.

Comment: I have just found the solution and updated my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

> In modern browsers use the input event. This event will fire when the user is typing into a text field, pasting, undoing, basically anytime the value changed from one value to another.

```
$('#number').on('input', function() { 
   $('#filter').submit();
});
```

Comment: The event fires, only the form is not submitted. I added _confirm("Test")_ and it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me I hope it also working for u

C# Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(string firstname)
   {
       return Json("Done");
   }
```

Razor Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var abc = document.getElementById('Number');
        abc.onchange = (function () {
            document.forms[0].submit();  
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "filter" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
            Number:
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBox("Number", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "Number" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 checkbox">
            Caption:
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBox("Caption", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "caption" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" id="submit1" class=" btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Do Not use submit as id or name of button it override the meaning of Java Script submit Method